# I am writing about examples of contemporary stereotyping of Native Americans, but what are more contemporary examples in movies and shows?

Tags: non-fiction, research

I am currently researching how stereotypes of Native Americans are still propagated in films today in the 21st century, just as they are in things like sports mascots and food brands, but I am having difficulty finding a variety of examples beyond a couple typical and older ones because of how typically and unfairly underrepresented Native American issues are in the film industry. There are of course Disney movies like Pocahontas and Peter Pan which feature very stereotypical portrayals, but those are older films, and the issue has not gone away since then.

I also checked the movies stack exchange site and they do not permit users to ask for examples of films, but since this pertains to scholarly writing and is not limited to specific films, I think it would be appropriate here to ask for data or inspiration.

Comment: I don't think this is really on-topic here, but you might enjoy watching [Longmire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1836037/)

Comment: Enjoying a movie isn't what the topic is about. This is clearly pertaining to writing, I had no idea stackexchange was so blatantly racist before recently.

Comment: Running a Google search for “Native American Stereotypes” brings up articles, academic papers and stereotypes about Native Americans.

Comment: It does bring up many articles, many of which I have already searched. I wouldn't be pointing out the problem unless I had already done research. Those articles are almost never of movies, shows and short films made in 2000 and beyond. Credible sources are ideal for research, but as I said, there is bias in the industry that obstructs research over the short term and prevents the compiling of more contemporary articles.

Comment: You specifically asked for examples of recent movies and shows with representations of Native Americans and noted the lack of such representation. Longmire is an example of a current TV show, based on a series of novels, which features Native American characters and storylines. I think the writers (of the books and TV scripts) have tried to write more nuanced characters, but it could well be argued that they fall back on old stereotypes at times. As such I thought it might be interesting for your study, particularly given the opportunity to compare the novels with the TV scripts.